# A word for someone who loves looking at handwriting - not studies it but purely for pleasure . .

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for someone who loves looking at handwriting - not studies it but purely for pleasure.

Comment: None that I know of, so I’ve made one up: _chirographphile_.

Comment: *[Graphobia](http://lisafulham298.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/graphobia-a-fear-of-writing/)* is a fear of writing or handwriting, and one might think *[agraphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agraphobia)* ought to be its opposite (or at least its absence).  Instead it's another fear, “the abnormal fear of sexual abuse”.  But consider the neologism *antigraphobia*.

Comment: If handwriting could be considered a form of art, you might consider them a dilettante.

Comment: @jwpat7 - I thought most "opposites" of _-phobe_ words were _-phile_ words, a la Barrie England's suggestion.

Comment: @J.R., right, but *[a-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-&allowed_in_frame=0)* as a prefix can mean *not*.  (Rather than  “ought to be its opposite” I should have written “is *an* opposite”.)

Comment: @jwpat7 I would have taken _agraphobia_ to mean the absence of _graphobia_. I'd be more partial to _graphophilia_ or _graphilia_ if we're coining neologisms. Even better would be _philography_.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Of course _a-_ can be used as a "negating prefix" of sorts, but I know of no instance where that prefix is used in front of a word ending with _-phobe, -phobia,_ or _-phile_. (Maybe there is one, but I think it would be atypical.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a neologism, **calligraphile** based on *[calligraphy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/calligraphy)*

> handwriting, esp beautiful handwriting considered as an art

and the suffix *[-phile](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/-phile)*

> indicating a person or thing having a fondness or preference for something specified

Comment: It was the first word that came to mind.  I say go for calligraphile.

Answer (score 0):

If a *[graphologist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graphologist)* engages in the study of handwriting, then a *grapholophile* (or *graphophile*) does it for love.

(Strictly speaking, it should be [*grapho-* + *-phile*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graphology?show=0&t=1384896662), but I like the sound of *grapholophile* better.)